# How do I used jQuery NoConflict Properly?

Tags: jquery

I am using two jQuery scripts. One is for controlling the drop down navigation on a site and the other is for a slideshow.

The one module is preceded with this code:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($){
 $.fn.dropmenu = function(custom)
```

The other one starts like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

As a result all of the functions in the second one show up as "not a function"

Since both of the scripts I am using are jQuery it seems that I should be able to get rid of the NoConflict function and these two scripts would play nicely together.

Sage advice welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

usually `$()` is the same as `jQuery()`.
noConflict 'frees' the $ from jquery so it can be used by other libraries.
So you could just be using `jQuery` instead of `$` everywhere.

Or you could do it like they show in their [examples](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) and pass `jQuery` into an anonymous function inside which you can use `$` again as usual:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($) { 
  $(function() {
    // more code using $ as alias to jQuery
  });
})(jQuery);
// other code using $ as an alias to the other library
```

So the problem in your example is that the first plugin calls noConflict() so $ can't be used by the second plugin.

You could solve it by putting everything thats inside `$(document).ready()` inside `(function($){`.

Or you get rid of `noConflict` altogether if you don't need it (if you're not using any other library that uses `$`).

Comment: Excellent explanation. Thank you for taking the time to clarify that.